# Proof in probability without Venn diagrams

Tags: probability

If we use Venn diagrams, it's easy to say that if $P(A)= P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B) \geq n$, then $P(A) \geq n$. But can we also prove such things mathematically? How would you be able to do that? Our class only teaches "proofs" with Venn diagrams but they don't feel like real, waterproof proofs.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if $E\subseteq F$ then $Pr(E)\leq Pr(F)$ is a direct result from the [axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms).  Your result follows from this observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms):

1. Probability is non-negative (and between 0 and 1).
2. $P(\Omega)=1$, where $\Omega$ is the entire probability space.
3. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events (they can't happen at the same time), then $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$. Strictly speaking this is valid even for infinitely many events, not just two, but it doesn't sound like you've gotten that far yet.

These three statements form the foundation of probability theory used by mathematicians. You can prove everything else from these, along with the basic laws for unions, intersections etc.

In your case, we have $P(A\cap B) = n$. Also, $A\cap B \subseteq A$, that's just basic set theory. Now, whenever we have $X\subseteq Y$, we have $P(X)\leq P(Y)$. This follows from the probability axioms by defining $Y=X\cup X'$, where $X$ and $X'$ are disjoint (this is definitely possible if $Y$ contains $X$, $X'$ is just the bits of $Y$ not in $X$). And then applying axiom 2 to say $P(Y) = P(X) + P(X')$ and axiom $1$ to say that $P(X)+P(X')\geq P(X)$. So $P(A)\geq P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any two events $A$ and $B$, we have that $A\cap B\subset A$ and $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$. Hence, if we have that
$$
P(A\cap B)\ge n,
$$
we also have that
$$
P(A)\ge n.
$$
The requirement that $P(A)=P(B)$ is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need $P(A)=P(B)$

It is always true that if $X\subseteq Y$, then $P(X)\leq P(Y)$ (this must be true *by definition*, otherwise $P$ is not a probability) for any two sets $X,Y$. And it's also always true that $A\cap B\subseteq A$.